# Has anyone added a DataGrid as a Child Node in a tree View using C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a win forms application. I am stuck with a problem in which I would use a Data Grid in a child node. Meaning, when a user expands a node, 
a data grid view displays where the child nodes array would of been displayed. I can not seem to figure out how to attach the data grid to the node so it collapses when the parent is collapsed and expands when the parent is expanded.
How do you attach the Data Grid to the be the node or in the node of the tree? 
I am open to alternate suggestions on how to do this.
Please help me.

Comment: Theoretically, this could possibly be done. However, the work needed to accomplish this is monumental. You would need to create a custom `TreeNode` object and handle all of the `Paint` events, etc. You are **FAR** better served coming up with an alternative UI approach for this. There is a reason why this is not already a part of the WinForms library.